# Why service error is send back as a string and not a json object?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services

I have simple `service`:

```
getCommandResult(fullCommand: string): Observable<any> {

    return this.http.post(this.callUrl, requestBody)
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body || { };
  }
  private handleError (error: Response | any) {
    return error.json();
  }
```

Here is my **call to that service**:

```
   this.myService.getCommandResult(commandFullString)
      .subscribe(res => {this.commandResponse = res;
          this.parseRestResponse();
        },
        error => {this.errorResponse = error;
          // **here I got string, not object to work with**
        },
        function() {
          doSomwthing()
        }
      );
```

When I get error from the service, I would like to return the object of error I got, but instead I get in return a string with this messae:

```
"You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable."
```

I'm trying to understand why response is working fine, I get object as expected. but on error I don't get the same object but only string and message.

Comment: could you try it without a `.catch`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`handleError` is supposed to return an Observable, not an object (as the message tells you

So your code should be

```
private handleError (error: Response | any) {
  return Observable.throw(error.json());
}
```

Comment: return Observable.throw(); is writing in console 404 not found error. Is there a way to avoid that?

Answer (score 1):

Please check out this [link](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/catch.md).

In short, `catch` is used to continue an observable sequence with the next observable you pass it. In your example, you are not passing an observable to `catch`.

Based on how the code looks, you should only remove the line with the `catch` (hence the error you are getting).